# Flutter: when swipe - background hang off?

Tags: flutter

I have got a app with a tabbar and when I swipe from one tap to another, the background is hanging. On page two is the background the UI from page one???
I wrap my Page in Container() but nothing works?

Here is Page 1:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzilv.jpg)

And here is Page 2 with the background from Page 1:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QdQL.jpg)

Comment: How do you suppose us to help you in your code without your code?

Comment: The Code of the Player is to long to Post. Maybe anyone knows the Problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to change the `Container` `color`? Try put black in Second page.
If you provide as with code we can help. Or try it yourself

Answer (score 0):

The Container color is black...
In Debug Mode the App works perfect.
Only the Release has the Problem.